# Multiple instances of jQuery plugin on single page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cycle

I've got a single page which has multiple instances of a thumbnail 'cycle' gallery. Problem is I would like to have those instances of the plugin start in a specific order and after a set time. And they are each going to only go through one transition. Can I set an interval of some sort?

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<figure role="container-1">
 <a href="#" class="singleFlip">
  <img src="/assets/img/1-img.jpg" border="0" />
  <img src="/assets/img/1-flipped.jpg" border="0" />
 </a>
</figure>

<figure role="container-2">
 <a href="#" class="singleFlip">
  <img src="/assets/img/2-img.jpg" border="0" />
  <img src="/assets/img/2-flipped.jpg" border="0" />
 </a>
</figure>

<figure role="container-3">
 <a href="#" class="singleFlip">
  <img src="/assets/img/3-img.jpg" border="0" />
  <img src="/assets/img/3-flipped.jpg" border="0" />
 </a>
</figure>
```

**Here is my JS:**

```
$('.singleFlip').cycle({
    fx:      'turnRight',
    delay:   10000,
    speed:   500,
    timeout: 8000,
    autostop: 1
});
```

**Answer:**

```
$('.singleFlip').each(function (i) {
 $(this).cycle({
  fx: 'turnRight',
  delay:   10000 * i,
  speed:   500,
  timeout: 8000,
  autostop: 1
 });
});
```

Comment: Yes, use .each to go over each instance, setting the options appropriately.

Comment: Right I have done that before for pager's and such but I'm looking to have the first container in the HTMl run through the cycle then the second and so on... Does that make sense?

Comment: Either set each cycle to delay for the same length of the time the previous cycles take to complete, or see if the plugin has a callback function that runs when a cycle finishes, and use that to call the next one

Comment: You can delay them by multiplying your delay by the index of the each. `delay: 10000*i`

Comment: Thanks guys! I updated this question with an updated answer. @KevinB

Comment: @TikaL13 remove the answer from your question and post it as an answer, then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the info guys!

```
$('.singleFlip').each(function (i) {
 $(this).cycle({
  fx: 'turnRight',
  delay:   10000 * i,
  speed:   500,
  timeout: 8000,
  autostop: 1
  });
});
```